# Securely storing a symmetric key in using the Android KeyChain

Tags: android, keystore, android-keystore

Given that it is not possible to store a symmetric key using the Android `KeyChain` API, is the following a secure way to store a symmetric key:

*Part One: Key Generation and Storage*

1. Generate `symmetric_key`
2. Generate `(private_key, public_key)`, store them in the `KeyChain`
3. Encrypt the `symmetric_key` using the `public_key` as follows: `encrypted_symmetric_key = public_encrypt(symmetric_key)`
4. Store `encrypted_symmetric_key` in local storage (`SharedPreferences`, `SQLite`, etc.)

*Part Two: Using the `symmetric_key`*

When the app wants to encrypt/decrypt something it:

1. Loads the `private_key` into memory from the `KeyChain`
2. Loads the `encrypted_symmetric_key` from disk
3. Obtains `symmetric_key := private_decrypt(encrypted_symmetric_key)`
4. `encrypt(symmetric_key, some_message)` or `decrypt(symmetric_key, some_ciphertext)`

Concerns:

1. Would a *rooted user* be able to obtain the `(private_key, public_key)` pair?
2. If the phone is not rooted, is the app that created the `(private_key, public_key)` pair the only user that can read the keypair?

Comment: The security depends on the Android version and if the device has a hardware or software keystore.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyChain.html):
The KeyChain class provides access to private keys and their corresponding certificate chains in credential storage.

Private key means that it's asymmetric (the private and public key are the two parts of an asymmetric key).

In your part 1 - you describe the preferred way to store a symmetric key on an Android device. Your part 2 is correct as well (at least to my knowledge).

As for your concerns - you are also correct. On a rooted device - the keys stored on the devices are vulnerable , and can be obtained by a person with access to that device. On a non rooted device - only the app will have access to the keys it creates.

In regard to rooting - you can use a root detection lib like RootShell (https://github.com/Stericson/RootShell) to detect if the device is rooted and then act accordingly (disable you app on that device or something similar) and you should also look into Google's SafetyNet (https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/index.html) to detect if the device is tampered with (it detects rooting as well).